# Compilation error TypeScript to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a Node.js program in TypeScript and after that I am compiling it to convert in ES5 JavaScript, but during compilation I am getting following error while using inheritance mechanism:

> ReferenceError: BaseDatastore is not defined` in javascript file

Code:

```
import BaseDatastore = require('./base-datastore');

class Datastore extends BaseDatastore {
    constructor(request: Request, response: Response) {
        console.log('method', request.method);
        super(request, response);
    }
}
export = Datastore;
```

And my base class is:

```
'use strict';

class BaseDatastore {
    constructor(request: Request, response: Response) {
        this.execute(request, response);
    }
    execute(request, response) {
        switch (request.method) {
            case 'POST': this.create(request, response);
                break;
            case 'PUT': this.update(request, response);
                break;
            case 'DELETE': this.delete(request, response);
                break;
            case 'GET':
                this.retrieve(request, response);
                break;
            default: console.log('No action taken');

        }
    }
}
export = BaseDatastore;
```

My compiled JavaScript file is here:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Datastore = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Datastore, _super);
    function Datastore(request, response) {
        console.log('Hola', request.method);
        _super.call(this, request, response);
    }
    return Datastore;
})(BaseDatastore);// This is the error point
module.exports = Datastore;
```

I just started to learn TypeScript and I don't know where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Both files are in same directory, If I remove inheritance then it works fine

Comment: Sorry I didn't get, where I use it as `string`

Comment: Are you sure this is solution? I don't think so

Comment: Getting same error

Comment: I am not familiar with require, but shouldn't it match the class name `require('./BaseDatastore');`